# Rabbitmq queue mirroring policy don't work when TTL policy is added to the cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, policy

On a five nodes rabbitmq cluster,I created two policies. One is for queue replication and the other is for TTL policies.

When I create a queue replication policy with the below commands, It works successfully, without any error.

**rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-three .*replica.* '{"ha-mode":"exactly","ha-params":2,"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'**

After creating the queue replication policy, I added a TTL policy with the below command. But when I add the TTL policy, the queue replication policy lost its functionality and don't work. When I remove the TTL leave policy, the replication policy starts to work properly again.

**rabbitmqctl set_policy TTL ".*" '{"message-ttl":3600000}' --apply-to queues**

I don't understand why TTL policy affects the queue replication policy. Did I miss something? I want two policies are working on the same cluster without effecting each other.